# Ext JS 4 - Editing only one row in a grid with multiple selected rows

Tags: extjs, extjs4

This is one of the requirements am working on.

I have a grid with the selmodel as 'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'. And to edit the grid rows, I can either use RowEditing or CellEditing plugins. So, here i what happens:

1. I select multiple checkboxes/rows.
2. Then I singleclick/doubeclick on one of the selected rows to edit the data in it.
3. This deselects all the other rows except for the one I double clicked to edit.

I don't want the other rows to be deselected. I should be able to singleclick/doubeclick on one of the selected rows and still keep the rest selected.

When all are rows are selected.
[image]

After i double click on a single row, you can see the other rows getting de-selected.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning false from the `beforedeselect` event will prevent the deselection. So, for the 1-click case, it should be easy to prevent deselection when editing. As luck gives it, it appears that the `beforedeselectevent` is fired after the `beforeedit` event (in 4.2.0 at least, that may not be stable across versions).

With row editing:

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
        ,pluginId: 'editing'
    })
]
,listeners: {
    beforedeselect: function(sm, record) {
        var plugin = this.getPlugin('editing');
        return !plugin.editing;
    }
    // The checkbox selection column should probably not be editable, but 
    // apparently it is not accounted for... So we must prevent edition on
    // this column, or you won't be able to deselect using the checkbox.
    ,beforeedit: function(editor, context) {
        return context.colIdx !== 0;
    }
}
```

With cell editing:

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
        ,pluginId: 'editing'
    })
]
,listeners: {
    beforedeselect: function(sm, record) {
        var plugin = this.getPlugin('editing');
        // In 4.2.0 there is apparently a bug that makes
        // plugin.editing always true
        return !plugin.getActiveEditor();
    }
    ,beforeedit: function(editor, context) {
       return context.colIdx !== 0;
    }
}
```

For the double click, you can elaborate on this strategy by capturing the deselect event and releasing it only if editing has not started.

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 2
        ,pluginId: 'editing'
    })
]
,listeners: {
    beforeedit: function(editor, context) {
        return context.colIdx !== 0;
    }
    ,beforedeselect: function(sm, record) {
        var plugin = this.getPlugin('editing');
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!plugin.editing) {
                // The true prevents the event from firing again,
                // and an infinite loop.
                sm.deselect(record, true);
            }
        }, 200);
        return false;
    }
}
```

However you have to make a guess concerning the user's double click delay. Too short and you might miss some double clicks, while too long will incur a unpleasant delay on the deselection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep selected records a variable, then edit the row. When everythings complete, try to re-select selected rows.

```
var selModel, selRows;
selModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
selRows = selModel.getSelection();

// after eediting, use the following
selModel.select(selRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass second parameter as true to select method to retain the previous selections as:

```
    selModel.select(rowsToSelect, true);
```

Sencha ExtJS docs for reference:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-select

Hope it helps!!